# Convert twoplustwo.com to RSS feed?

Tags: rss

I want to convert a discussion group (www.twoplustwo.com) to an RSS feed.

What is the easiest way to do that?

Similar question: [scraping a non RSS page to generate a feed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2251937/scraping-a-non-rss-page-to-generate-a-feed)

Comment: Forum is vBulletin and it has rss feed support, are you sure that they don't have enabled it? If it is disabled, you could still ask if they very kind enough to enable it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use jsoup html parser to get data if you use Java. With jsoup you can use css selectors to select html elements.

http://jsoup.org/